# Is there any difference between normal and static local variables in static methods?

Tags: c++, static, static-methods, static-members

```
class A
{
    static void f(void)
    {
        int a;
        static int b;
    }
};
```

Is there any (formal or practical) difference between `a` and `b`?

Comment: `b` will retain its value across calls, while `a` will be reinitialized every time...

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Yes, `a` is allocated on the stack, `b` is allocated in the data-section. The fact the the function is `static` does not effect the "behavior" of variables in it (i.e., would be the same for a non-static function).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
    static void func()
    {
        static int a = 10;
        int b = 10;
        a++;
        b++;
        std::cout << a << " " << b << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a, b;
    a.func();
    b.func();
    a.func();
    return 0;
}
```

`a` is shared across all instances of `func`, but `b` is local to each instance, so the output is:

```
11 11
12 11
13 11
```

http://ideone.com/kwlra3

Answer (score 2):

Yes both are different. For every call `a` will be created whereas `b` will be created only once and it is same for all the objects of type `A`. By same I mean, all the objects share a single memory of `b`.

Comment: Does this mean the value stays the same no matter how many 'A' objects are created?

Comment: Yes it is always same.

Comment: @laiello That´s what static means (here): It does not depend on the object; it´s the same for the whole class.

Comment: And note that this would be true even if `f` were not static.

Comment: Gotcha. Statics have been a hard concept to wrap my head around for some reason.